# Static branch prediction / GCC optimization

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, assembly, x86-64

Consider the following C program:

```
void bar();
void baz();

void foo( int a ) {
    if ( a ) {
        bar();
    }
    else {
        baz();
    }
}
```

On my x86-64-based computer, the instructions generated by GCC with the -O1 optimization level gives:

```
 0: sub    $0x8,%rsp
 4: test   %edi,%edi
 6: je     14 <foo+0x14>
 8: mov    $0x0,%eax
 d: callq  12 <foo+0x12> # relocation to bar
12: jmp    1e <foo+0x1e>
14: mov    $0x0,%eax
19: callq  1e <foo+0x1e> # relocation to baz
1e: add    $0x8,%rsp
22: retq
```

whereas adding the -freorder-blocks optimization parameter (included in -O2) turns the code into:

```
 0: sub    $0x8,%rsp
 4: test   %edi,%edi
 6: jne    17 <foo+0x17>
 8: mov    $0x0,%eax
 d: callq  12 <foo+0x12> # relocation to baz
12: add    $0x8,%rsp
16: retq   
17: mov    $0x0,%eax
1c: callq  21 <foo+0x21> # relocation to bar
21: add    $0x8,%rsp
25: retq
```

what is mainly a change from *jump equals* to *jump not equals*. I know that up to Pentium 4, static branch prediction on a conditional forward branch was considered not taken by the processor (it seems that static prediction became random on further Intel processors), thus I imagine this optimization is dealing with this.

Assuming that and refering to the *jne* optimized version, it would mean that the *else* block is in fact considered to be more likely executed than the *if* block in the program flow.

But what does it mean exactly? Since there is no assumption on the *a* value in the *foo* function by the compiler, such probability relies on the programmer's writings only (who could in fact have used `if ( !a )` instead of `if ( a )` and inverted function calls).

Does that mean that it should be considered as a good practice to treat *if* conditional blocks as exceptional cases (and not the normal execution flow)?

That is:

```
if ( !cond ) {
    // exceptional code
}
else {
    // normal continuation
}
```

instead of:

```
if ( cond ) {
    // normal continuation
}
else {
    // exceptional code
}
```

(of course, one could prefer using return statement inside relevant block to limit indentation size).

Answer (score 4):

I once had significant amount of performance optimization actions on ARM(7,9). It was plain C, dumb enough compiler (SDT AFAIR). One of the way to save some CPU resources was to analyse `if` branches and rewrite `if` condition so normal flow doesn't break linear instructions sequence. This had positive effect both because of CPU prediction block more efficient usage and more efficient code segment memory cache usage.

I think here we see optimization which is very close. In first code fragment both branches lead to normal sequence being broken (line with lavel `6` for one branch and `12` for another). In second fragment one branch instructions are ordered up to `retq` and other branch sequence has single jump (not worse than it was in first fragment). Please pay attention to 2 `retq` instructions.

So as I can see this is not the question of `je` or `jne` but rather question of blocks reordering so branches are linear instructions sequence with one of them entered without any `jump` and full prediction block power saved.

Regarding to "why GCC prefers one branch over another"... I see in documentation this can be result of static branch prediction (based on calls inside translation unit?). Anyway I'd recommend to play with `__builtin_expect` to have more detailed answer.

Comment: Yes... But the different return points could just have also been realized on a `je` version. And GCC does this if/else block reordering _consciously_: in the initial program changing the `if ( a )` to `if ( !a )` compiles to exactly the opposite: from a `jne` (non-optimized) version to a `je` (branch-order optimized) version. I can't believe GCC does this change only to make fun of me! :)

Comment: I think in any case __builtin_expect should help this ;-). http://blog.man7.org/2012/10/how-much-do-builtinexpect-likely-and.html